# JavaFX: Display PDF in WebView

Tags: pdf, javafx, webview, jxbrowser, webengine

I need to display a PDF inside the default WebView of JavaFX. I assumed, that i would easily be able to do that like this.

```
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.web.WebEngine;
import javafx.scene.web.WebView;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class ShowPdfTest extends Application {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch();
    }

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) throws Exception {
        WebView webView = new WebView();
        WebEngine engine = webView.getEngine();
        Scene scene = new Scene(webView);
        primaryStage.setScene(scene);
        primaryStage.show();

//        engine.load("https://www.google.com");
        engine.load("http://www.orimi.com/pdf-test.pdf");
    }
}
```

I was wrong. Nothing happens. It seems like the WebEngine has no built-in PDF-Renderer. I tried [JxBrowser](https://www.teamdev.com/jxbrowser) which worked fine, but is a rather costly alternative.

So is there any way to display a PDF directly inside the default WebView component?

Comment: You can use [Mozilla Pdf.js](https://github.com/mozilla/pdf.js/) in your WebView.

Comment: OK, but what if i have something like this?

https://www.cs.tut.fi/~jkorpela/html/iframe-pdf.html

Comment: You don't need iframe for Pdf.js! You can call your pdf file with Pdf.js in  WebView.

Comment: No, i get that i can use Pdf.js to display a PDF inside a WebView. But my goal is to render PDFs dynamically like any other browser. So if a webpage has ebedded a PDF inside iframe or JavaScript i want to be able to show the whole page with the embedded PDF.

Answer (score 1):

> JxBrowser which worked fine, but is a rather costly alternative.

If you your application is an open-source project, you can obtain the JxBrowser Open-Source license [here](https://www.teamdev.com/jxbrowser#licensing-pricing).