# Show pdf in JavaFX application

Tags: pdf, javafx, webview

I read the following posts: [JavaFX: Display PDF in WebView](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45062293/javafx-display-pdf-in-webview), [Displaying pdf in JavaFX](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18207116/displaying-pdf-in-javafx)

But there occur some problems for me:

1. The links of JPedalFX do not work any more and I can't find example codes on the web.
2. I don't want to use Swing-components in an JavaFX-application.
3. The solution with PDF JS doesn't work either, because Maven is used in the project and I don't want to put the library in the resources folder.
4. JxBrowser would be a possible solution but cost too much.

Any ideas?

Comment: why are you opposed to using swing components with FX? they're compatible

Comment: Convert the `PDF` to `HTML` and use `WebView`.

Comment: https://dzone.com/articles/converting-pdf-html-using