# How to view PDF in JavaFX desktop application without actually downloading the PDF to the client machine?

Tags: java, pdf, javafx, ftp, javafx-8

I am working on a JavaFX desktop project in which I have to upload the documents of an individual on the server. In order to view the document, I do not want to first download the PDF file to client machine and then view the PDF file. Is there any way I can view the PDF file without downloading it just like how it opens in the browser.

Comment: No, that is impossible. Even in the browser, you are still downloading the file; it's just done in the background to a temporary folder.

Comment: Maybe this article can help you: [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45062293/javafx-display-pdf-in-webview](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45062293/javafx-display-pdf-in-webview)

Comment: @flaxel - That won't work with an FTP server. You cannot open files directly from an FTP server. It's called File **Transfer** Protocol for a reason :)

Comment: As you _must_ transfer the file to view its contents, use `File.createTempFile()` and `deleteOnExit()` to avoid clutter.